# Do coal stoves lead to creosote buildup/chimney fire risk?

Tags: heating, woodstove

One of the reasons we put in a coal stove as an alternative heat source was because several sources said coal stoves don't have creosote buildup, reducing the risk of chimney fire.

The instructions that came with the stove, however, state that we have to inspect the chimney for creosote buildup and clean it out once a year.

So do coal stoves have buildup leading to chimney fire risk, or don't they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, to the best of my knowledge all combustion creates some form of creosote regardless of the fuel source. Wood tar and Coal tar are the most abundant and well known forms of creosote.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creosote#Lignite-tar_creosote)

Comment: Having worked with coal-fired steam locomotives, I can say that even capably-fired coal leaves build-up. Just like we must clean our fire tubes, the asker needs to clean his chimney. We have the advantage of always tending our fire to ensure good combustion and have a short hot flue. A fireplace or stove lacks both those advantages.

Clean your chimney. Chimney fires are **awful** (former firefighter too).

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to schedule a chimney sweep this spring!

Answer (score 1):

Trains use bituminous coal or lignite, which are lower (cheaper) grades than you're likely to use in your house (i.e., anthracite). Anthracite produces no creosote, although it did burn hotter, so you'll need to make sure you reduce or eliminate other combustible materials.

Comment: Eh -- old steam roads in the East preferred anthracite -- the other stuff was used only begrudgingly for multiple reasons

Answer (score 1):

Been burning anthracite for decades. Absolutely nothing but fine ash in the 20 foot chimney. I burned some cheap bituminus coal for two weeks last winter and the chimney plugged with tar and soot and was just an overall smokey, stinking mess. Absolutely no smoke with anthracite. The anthracite is well worth the additional cost. Stay away from soft coal, trust me on this.